# Nvidia stops working after repairing Grub

Tags: grub2, nvidia

Everything was working fine with my GPU. I had to use boot-repair, and it added grub to some partitions. After that I only get low resolution Ubuntu, it does not detect the driver. nvidia-settings give this

```
 ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
 ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

I went through some questions here, they suggest to edit /etc/default/grub I did that by doing  `nouveau.modeset=0` or `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` and `sudo update-grub`, no changes.

Comment: This ^^^ and disabling Secure Boot. Also it's likely unrelated to what Boot-Repair did or didn't. It's likely to be related with a UEFI settings reset that enabled a previously disable Secure Boot.

Comment: I uninstalled, rebooted, installed again without DKM, and that solved the problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I uninstalled, rebooted, installed again without DKM, and that solved the problem.

*This answer comes "as-is" from the original author of the question who [posted this solution in comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145962/nvidia-stops-working-after-repairing-grub/1276346#comment1902608_1145962).*